# Python 2.7: inheritance with OrderedDict Attribute error <myclass> class has no attribute '_OrderedDict__root'

Tags: python, inheritance, attributeerror

I am trying to write a python class that inherits from OrderedDict using python 2.7.10.

The very basic class looks like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class Game (OrderedDict):

  def __init__(self,theTitle="",theScore=0):
    self['title'] = theTitle
    self['score'] = theScore


  def __str__(self):
    return "hi"
    #return 'title: ' + self['title'] + ", score:" + str(self['score'])
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
 (metacrit) Jasons-MBP:mc jtan$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from game import Game
>>> g = Game('battlezone',100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "game.py", line 7, in __init__
    self['title'] = theTitle
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 64, in __setitem__
    root = self.__root
AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute '_OrderedDict__root'
>>>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
I'm pretty sure OrderedDict is in this version of Python which was the first thing I though and not sure where to go to yet. 
I'm not python native, as yet.

Comment: The OrderedDict implementation is as an container object. And you didn't initialize it in __init__(): OrderedDict.__init__(self). That is one thing that might provoke the AttributeError. The second is that following protocols and interfaces of real dict, OrderedDict might not let you assign attributes without some tricks first to fool it. Don't forget, all methods are inherited and your new object behaves just like an original OrderedDict. Take a look at its implementation in collections or, there is OrderedDict module for Python versions < 2.6 and see what you have to override, if anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten to initialize the base class. In your code, `__init__` only initializes `Game` elements and fails to initialize the underlying `OrderedDict`. You must explicitely call the base class `__init__` method:

```
class Game (OrderedDict):

  def __init__(self,theTitle="",theScore=0):
    OrderedDict.__init__(self)    
    self['title'] = theTitle
    self['score'] = theScore


  def __str__(self):
    return "hi"
    #return 'title: ' + self['title'] + ", score:" + str(self['score'])
```

You can then do successfully:

```
>>> g = Game('battlezone',100)
>>> g
Game([('title', 'battlezone'), ('score', 100)])
>>> str(g)
'hi'
```

As `__repr__` has not been overriden, you can see the `OrderedDict` representation.